# how to import typescript class into jest unit test? no construct signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am working on a nodeJs project, using typescript.
I wanted to import a class and use it in unit-test (jest), however the following errors keep coming up.

Is there any work to make it work?
I've tried changing import syntax (adding/ removing '*').
Some threads also suggesting to use class-transformer, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Please let me know if you need any more infos.
Appreciated all your helps!

```
error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
      Type 'SearchParams' has no construct signatures.

    const model: any = new SearchParams();
```

unit_test.ts

```html
    import { SearchParams } from "../../../src/controllers/requests/SearchParams";
import { validate } from "class-validator";
import {
      IsDefined,
      IsBoolean,
      IsString,
      IsEmail,
      IsNumberString,
      IsNotEmpty,
      MaxLength,
      IsNumber,
      Matches,
      Validate
    } from 'class-validator';
import { DateConditionCheck } from '../../../src/controllers/validators/DateConditionCheck';

     describe("GET: search/api", () => {
       const model: any = new SearchParams();
       model.depArea = 'HND';
    
         it('should throw an error message when date input is incorrect', async () => {
          return validate(model).then(errors => {
            expect(errors.length).toBe(1);
            expect(model.dd).toThrow('Date condition seems wrong!');
          });
         });
      });
```

```html
import {
  IsDefined,
  IsBoolean,
  IsString,
  IsEmail,
  IsNumberString,
  IsNotEmpty,
  MaxLength,
  IsNumber,
  Matches,
  Validate
} from 'class-validator'
import { DateConditionCheck } from '../validators/DateConditionCheck'

export class SearchParams {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MaxLength(20)
  depArea: string;
}
```